# Encrypt a virtual hard disk on Windows 7 Home Premium?

Tags: windows, encryption, vhd

I have a virtual hard disk file (*.VHD) and as Windows 7 Home Premium user, I don't have BitLocker to encrypt this hard disk. So is there any alternative way for me to do so?

Answer (score 1):

I am tempted to give you a -1 for lack of research, because I can't imagine Google would have returned the almost universal [TruCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) with even a sub-par search string...

I am going with the benefit of the doubt though, and posting TruCrypt, its free and open and well respected.

Comment: Nitpick: It's TrueCrypt with an 'e'.

Comment: @Karan right you are.

Comment: @AthomSfere I had downloaded TrueCrypt even before I posted this question. But I'm an inexperienced user so I couldn't make the program encrypt an existing partition - which is previously attached from a VHD file. I'm really looking for an article about this.

Comment: @user433531 your question reflected neither of those points.